# Alien invasion thwarted by tornadoes/weather

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

Science fiction novel where aliens give up invading Earth after experiencing severe weather in US (Tornado Alley/hurricanes?). I think I read it before 1990. Some small chance has Red Cross symbol on a structure’s roof on the cover.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a novella, not a novel, but this sounds fairly close to ["The Gentle Earth"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55698) (1957) by Christopher Anvil.

I'll try to edit in some quotes later, but an alien invasion starts to go awry when they land in Tornado Alley.  Quoting from a review on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29474693-the-gentle-earth):

> A lengthy description of a Venusian military campaign unleashed against the USA.
>
> Despite lengthy planning and a 50+ year technological advantage, the Venusians miscalculate both politically- their crude attempt to isolate the USA politically is a total failure- and militarily. They also never quite get to grips with Earth weather and environments

Comment: You can read the story at http://baencd.freedoors.org/Books/The%20Trouble%20With%20Humans/1416521429__13.htm

Comment: The original "Astounding Science Fiction" cover:  https://www.collectorshowcase.fr/IMAGES2/ast_5711.jpg

Comment: This is it. Thank you so much! This question has been bothering me for years. And, I appreciate the links.